# changing gitlab's user-presented docker container names

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab

I have GitLab Omnibus running in a Kubernetes cluster, with NodePort ports for web (`80`) and the docker container registry (`5050`).

I've setup Ingress URLs (`www.gitlab.xxx.yyy`, `registry.gitlab.xxx.yyy`) so that clients don't have to know the NodePort assignments.

The config `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` has:

```
registry_external_url 'https://registry.gitlab.xxx.yyy:5050'
```

The problem is that the registry URL shown to users is 
`registry.gitlab.xxx.yyy:5050/foo/bar`

when what it really should be is

`registry.gitlab.xxx.yyy/foo/bar`

How can I configure GitLab to show a custom URL on its pages but still run the service on port `5050`?

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/packages/container_registry.html) about configuring the domain for container registry:

> If you would like to use a separate domain [...than gitlab default domain...], all you have to do is configure the domain name under which the Container Registry will listen to.

You just need to change your config in `gitlab.rb`

```
registry_external_url 'https://registry.gitlab.xxx.yyy'
```

Comment: `registry_external_url` changes the port-- what you have means it will be listening on port 443, not port 5050.

Comment: if you want your user to be shown with `registry.gitlab.xxx.yyy/foo/bar` it will have to listen on port 443 somehow, else you need the port in the uri.